# Targeting hidden inputs by id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, hidden-field

For some reason I am unable to retrieve hidden inputs by id using jQuery.

I can do

```
> $('input')
[<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id checked>​, <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id checked>​, <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id>​, <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id>​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"1-rooms">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"2-rooms" checked>​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"3-rooms" checked>​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"4-rooms">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"5-rooms">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"over-5-rooms">​, <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id>​, <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id>​, <input type=​"checkbox" name=​"property-type" id>​]
```

which gets me all of the inputs on the page nicely, including those of type=hidden.

I can also do

```
> $('input[type="hidden"]')
[<input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"1-rooms">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"2-rooms" checked>​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"3-rooms" checked>​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"4-rooms">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"5-rooms">​, <input type=​"hidden" name=​"no-of-rooms" id=​"over-5-rooms">​]
```

which gets me all of my hidden fields. Note they all have an id.

For some reason trying to target those inputs by their id, either with or without the `[type="hidden"]` included, will get me an empty list.

```
> $('input[type="hidden"]#2-rooms')
[]
> $('input#2-rooms')
[]
```

I have managed to find a workaround by simply not targeting them by their ID-s, but it would be useful to know why this doesn't seem possible.

**EDIT**

Using just `$('#2-rooms')` works for me and is apparently the best approach.
However, I am still unsure as to why `$('input#2-rooms')` is not working, as I *had* in fact included the html5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), and I understand ids beginning with numbers should in this case be okay.

Comment: Did you happen to try `$('#2-rooms')`

Comment: Most likely you aren't using HTML5, and before HTML5, ID's could not start with a numeric character. Try using  the html5 doctype to confirm: `<!doctype html>` (or you could just change the id's to not use a numeric character as it's first character)

Comment: Silly me for not trying `$('#2-rooms')`, which does work (although I'd still prefer to specify that it is an input for clarity..). I also now tried `$('input#over-5-rooms')` which doesn't start with a number and does work as well. I have included the html5 doctype, so this shouldn't be the issue, also confirmed by the fact that `$('#2-rooms')` seems to work fine.

Comment: The permutations of the 2 queries you have shown in your question seem to work fine in FF and Chrome and even IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/3KwKr/ but as others have said if you are querying by id only using the id is plenty as identifiers should be unique across the page.

Comment: @Elise It is better to use `$('#2-rooms')` instead of `$('input#2-rooms')` - I believe the latter would find all input element and then matches the ID attribute instead of just looking for the element with ID which is the fastest known selector.

Comment: @Vega: +1 Good advise. Out of curiosity I also wanted to know what the performance difference is and how much faster it is to just use the identifier. Just using the identifier is a lot faster than element-id: http://jsperf.com/id-vs-element-with-id

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Here is a nice article on writing efficient selectors http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: Have you tried `$('input:hidden')`?

Comment: This might sound weird but, for HTML: `<input type="hidden" id="inp1">` and jQuery: `$('input[type=hidden]#inp1')` I do get the object `[<input type=​"hidden" id=​"inp1">​]`. I am using `Chrome v28` and `jQuery v1.9.1`

Comment: @Sourabh I never quite understood the issue myself, but I believe it has to do with input names beginning with numbers, and since `inp1` begins with a letter it would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wild card ends with using attribute selector, instead of using id selector.

```
$('[id$=rooms]')
```

OR, use `*` for contains

```
$('[id*=rooms]')
```

Or if you have single element with id, **[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TRB7B/2/)**

```
 $('#2-rooms')
```

**Edit** If you have single element with id then you can simply use id selector `$('#2-rooms')` If more then one elements have same id then it is not valid html you should have unique ids. If you have ids with pattern like 2-rooms, 3-rooms then you have use attribute selector with wild cards.

Comment: OP has found a work around, the question is why wont the id selector work.

Comment: I think OP in OP solution we have to give input in selector like $('input#2-rooms')

Comment: This does work as well, as does targeting individual hidden fields using `$('input[id="2-rooms"]')`. Thanks!

Comment: @Elise Even `$('input[type="hidden"]').filter(function () { return this.id === '2-rooms'; })` should work well, but it is a overkill when you just want to select an element with ID such as `#2-rooms` which could be easily achieved by `$('#2-rooms')`.

Comment: You can simply use id selector if you have single element $('#2-rooms'), http://jsfiddle.net/TRB7B/2/